# Get Shell Icon with only a file extension

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-shell, shell-icons

I want to get the windows system icon(s) for a file type without necessarily providing an existing file path (required by [SHGetFileInfo](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx&ei=SM4_UObiH83oigKM9ICQDA&usg=AFQjCNGcorBOIKoRPzRO7DhlB_fYyrdItQ))

Is this possible, or do I have to resort to creating temporary files or reading the registry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes is possible using file extension as first parameter in [SHGetFileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
You must also use SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES flags.

Comment: Ahh I didn't realize this was possible. To do it you have to use the SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES flag. You may want to update your answer to include this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case you were interested in an implementation I had a blog post on this in 2004 that can still be found here (about the third entry down) [Old blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20081225164919/http://www.dotnetjunkies.com/WebLog/malio/default.aspx)